# Carousel View in Xamarin forms not responding to Image button in the view

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, icommand, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I cannot get the image buttons to move the carousel image to the next in the list. when I click the imagebutton and step through the code the Position is changing properly, but does not move the carousel in the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for both my View and View Model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Das_Local.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Das_Local.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="375">
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </CarouselView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Whats New in the Local"  FontSize="Title" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,-10"/>
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <CarouselView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">
                        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True">
                                    <StackLayout Margin="0,0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding ArticleTitle}"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Title"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding ArticleTextBody}" FontSize="Body" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CarouselView>
                    <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Source="left.png" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                 HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" Command="{Binding ChangePositionCommand}" CommandParameter="L"/>
                    <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Source="right.png" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                 HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" Command="{Binding ChangePositionCommand}" CommandParameter="R"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Das_Local.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Das_Local.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Title = "SMART 29";
            images = GetCarouselImages();
            articles = GetCarouselArticles();
            ChangePositionCommand = new Command(ChangePosition);
        }
        private ObservableCollection<CarouselImages> images;
        public ObservableCollection<CarouselImages> Images
        {
            get { return images; }
            set
            {
                images = value;
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CarouselImages> GetCarouselImages()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<CarouselImages>
            {
                new CarouselImages { ImageUrl= "anglewrappedduct.jpg" },
                new CarouselImages { ImageUrl = "ductrun.jpg" },
                new CarouselImages { ImageUrl = "offset.jpg" },
                new CarouselImages { ImageUrl = "panels.jpg" }
            };
        }

        ObservableCollection<CarouselArticles> articles;
        public ObservableCollection<CarouselArticles> Articles
        {
            get { return articles; }
            set
            {
                articles = value;
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<CarouselArticles> GetCarouselArticles()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<CarouselArticles>
            {
                new CarouselArticles { ArticleTitle= "This Title", ArticleTextBody = "Body of the article will go here"},
                new CarouselArticles { ArticleTitle = "Another Title", ArticleTextBody = "Just what I need more text for the article body" },
                new CarouselArticles { ArticleTitle = "My Third Title", ArticleTextBody = "I am getting burned out on writing random things"},
                new CarouselArticles { ArticleTitle = "Bravo", ArticleTextBody = "whats the deal with these free channels"}
            };
        }
        public ICommand ChangePositionCommand { get; set; }
        private CarouselArticles selectedarticle;
        public CarouselArticles SelectedArticle
        {
            get { return selectedarticle; }
            set
            {
                selectedarticle = value;
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }
        private int position;
        public int Position
        {
            get { return position; }
            set
            {
                position = value;
                selectedarticle = articles[position];

                OnPropertyChange(nameof(SelectedArticle));
            }
        }
        private void ChangePosition(object obj)
        {
            string direction = (string)obj;
            if (direction == "L")
            {
                if (position == 0)
                {
                    Position = articles.Count - 1;
                    return;
                }

                Position -= 1;
            }
            else if (direction == "R")
            {
                if (position == articles.Count - 1)
                {
                    Position = 0;
                    return;
                }

                Position += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: neither SelectedArtcile nor Position are bound to any properties of your CarouselView

Comment: thanks, I don't know how I was overlooking that, I forgot to bind the current item. works now, I appreciate it.